# Randomise numbers without repeating the number

Tags: vba, excel

My end result is to output the names in column A to column B in random order.

I have been researching but cant seem to find what I need.

So far I can kinda of randomise the numbers but its still giving me repeated numbers + the heading (A1).

I need it to skip A1 because this is the heading\title of the column and start at A2.

I assume once that is working correctly I add the randomNumber to a random name to `Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(randomNumber, "B").Value` ...something like that...?

OR if there is a better way of doing this let me know.

```
Sub Meow()

Dim CountedRows As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim PreviousCell As Integer
Dim randomNumber As Integer

i = 1
PreviousCell = 0

CountedRows = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If CountedRows < 2 Then
 ' If its only the heading then quit and display a messagebox
   No_People_Error = MsgBox("No People entered or found, in column 'A' of Sheetname 'Master Sheet'", vbInformation, "Pavle Says No!")
   Exit Sub
End If


Do Until i = CountedRows
 randomNumber = Int((Rnd * (CountedRows - 1)) + 1) + 1

 If Not PreviousCell = randomNumber Then
    Debug.Print randomNumber
    i = i + 1
 End If

 PreviousCell = randomNumber
Loop

Debug.Print "EOF"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for the `Randomize` instruction. Are you calling it anywhere?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, `Randomize()` just resets the RNG in VB.  I think the problem here is that @Pavle is only check the last number generated for repeats. If you want to generate a random order, you can generate a random number (0 to 1 from `Rnd`) for each row and then sort the original data by the random numbers.  If you want to do it all in VBA, then it is a matter of generating an array of randoms and sorting the new data by that.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I am writing some stuff now and post it later when its working :)

Comment: If you want to get random numbers making sure there will be no repetition (at least before 2 billions generations first), may I suggest you to have a look at the [Linear Congruential Generator](http://www.econ-pol.unisi.it/fineng/unigen_pres.pdf) (p.s. there's a code snippet at the last slide). All you need to do then is to study a little rule and make the numbers integers to use them as row indexes. But I would suggest not to use the classic VBA Rnd(), which uses a basic algorithm that might lead to repetitions much easier than the simples LGC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed something similar previously using two collections.

Fill one collection with the original data and leave the other collection empty.  Then keep randomly picking an index in the first collection, adding the value at that index to the second collection and delete the value from the original collection.  Set that to loop until the first collection is empty and the second collection will be full of a randomly sorted set of unique values from your starting list.

***Edit: I've thought about it again and you don't really need the second collection.  You can pop a random value from the first collection and write it directly to the worksheet, incrementing the row each time:

```
Sub Meow()

Dim lst As New Collection
Dim rndLst As New Collection
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim No_People_Error As Integer

startRow = 2
endRow = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

If Cells(startRow, 1).Value = "" Then
 ' If its only the heading then quit and display a messagebox
   No_People_Error = MsgBox("No People entered or found, in column 'A' of Sheetname 'Master Sheet'", vbInformation, "Pavle Says No!")
   Exit Sub
End If

' Fill a collection with the original list
Dim i As Integer
For i = startRow To endRow
    lst.Add Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i


' Create a randomized list collection
' Use i as a row counter
Dim rowCounter As Integer
rowCounter = startRow

Dim index As Integer

Do While lst.Count > 0

    'Find a random index in the original collection
    index = Int((lst.Count - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    'Place the value in the worksheet
    Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value = lst(index)
    'Remove the value from the list
    lst.Remove (index)
    'Increment row counter
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

P.S. I hope there's an excellent story behind naming your sub `Meow()` :P

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick hack...

```
  Sub Meow()
    'On Error GoTo err_error
    Dim CountedRows As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim PreviousCell As Integer
    Dim randomNumber As Integer
    Dim nums() As Integer
    PreviousCell = 0

    CountedRows = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim nums(CountedRows - 1)
    If CountedRows < 2 Then
     ' If its only the heading then quit and display a messagebox
       No_People_Error = MsgBox("No People entered or found, in column 'A' of Sheetname 'Master Sheet'", vbInformation, "Pavle Says No!")
       Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 1 To CountedRows
    rand:
        randomNumber = randomNumbers(1, CountedRows, nums)
        nums(i - 1) = randomNumber
        Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("B" & randomNumber) = Range("A" & i)
    Next i


    Exit Sub
    err_error:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    End Sub

    Public Function randomNumbers(lb As Integer, ub As Integer, used As Variant) As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    r = Int((ub - lb + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    For Each j In used
        If j = r Then
            r = randomNumbers(lb, ub, used)
        Else
            randomNumbers = r
        End If
    Next

    End Function
```

Comment: Hey Adrian, works great thank you :)
which part of this can i modify to not use the title aka A1 I need this to not be included....

Comment: If I had to guess it would be the for `i = 1...` change to for `i = 2...`

Comment: No worries :-), yeah change i=2 To CountedRows and change nums(i-1) to nums(i-2)...